# mysql-Join two tables get the most recent date and value and nearest date and value 12 month ago

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,the product table and meter reading table which joined by the serial number, I want to display all the machines in product table and the most recent meter reading and date in the meter reading table, also nearest date and meter reading 12 month ago.

I have the query like this, but the didn't get the correct date and meter reading from 12 month ago.

```
select a.Model,a.SerialNumber,a.UnitNumber,a.RecentMeterRead,a.RecentMeterReadDate,b.MeterRead12MonthAgo,b.MeterRead12MonthAgoDate,(a.RecentMeterRead-b.MeterRead12MonthAgo)/12 AS HourByMonth 
from
(select s1.ITEMCODE AS Model,s1.SERIALNUMBER as SerialNumber,s1.UNITNUMBER as UnitNumber,
max(s9.METERREAD) as RecentMeterRead,max(s9.METERREADDATE)as RecentMeterReadDate
FROM wk001.serf01 s1  
left join wk001.serf09 s9 
on s1.SERIALNUMBER=s9.SERIALNUMBER 
where  s1.BILLTOCUSTOMERCODE='02366'
group by s1.SERIALNUMBER
order by s9.METERREADDATE desc ) as a 

 left outer join 

(select s1.SERIALNUMBER,
s9.METERREAD as MeterRead12MonthAgo,s9.METERREADDATE as MeterRead12MonthAgoDate
FROM wk001.serf01 s1  
left join wk001.serf09 s9 
on s1.SERIALNUMBER=s9.SERIALNUMBER 
where  s1.BILLTOCUSTOMERCODE='02366'
group by s1.SERIALNUMBER
having s9.METERREADDATE<=date_sub(max(s9.METERREADDATE),interval 12 month)
order by s9.METERREADDATE desc) as b
on  a.SERIALNUMBER=b.SERIALNUMBER 
group by a.SERIALNUMBER
order by a.RecentMeterReadDate desc,b.MeterRead12MonthAgoDate DESC;
```